# Set width of one div to the width of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a search button on the top left which is making my search bar toggle. What i want to achieve here is this.

I basically want the search bar to be the same width as the "welcome" header right above it. the Welcome is not inside a header tag it is actually inside a list tag.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ4PF/) i have created.

This is what i tried.

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
var x = $("#page2content :ul").width();
$("#example_filter").css('width', 'x');
});
```

I basically want to get the width of the welcome header width and store it in a var
and then pass that var in to the css width of the search bar. can anyone please advice what i did wrong? Please also can u give me a smilar solution as i dont want to change the width of the search bar by css directly i want to set its css via jquery. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your fiddle so it reflects the code you posted here, and post the relevant HTML.

Comment: edited, sorry about that.

Comment: There is no element with id "example_filter," so your selector isn't working.

Comment: The search bar's id is example_filter , if you are using chrome right click and inspect element.

Comment: Are you sure? Look at your HTML. Search for "example_filter." There is *no element* with that ID in your fiddle.

Comment: That is because i am using datatables api . check out my external resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- This selector is incorrect `#page2content :ul`, remove the `:`, so `#page2content ul`

2- The returned `x` is a number, you will need to add `px` to it to make it a valid CSS property. And you will need to target the `input`

```
var x = $("#page2content ul").width();
$("#example_filter label input").css('width', x + 'px');
```